# Error with swift code don't know what to write for return?

Tags: json, swift, swift2, nsurl

i can't find out what to return, trying to get an API however no information is producing in the output from the NSURL link, the events is a random array that is hardcoded ..Thanks

```
 func parse (jsonResult: AnyObject?) {

     if let dictionary = jsonResult as? NSDictionary {

        if let event = dictionary["EVENT_ID"] as? NSDictionary {
           print("Event is \(event)")
           if let eventName = event["EVENT_NAME"] as? NSNumber {
              print ("Event name is \(eventName)")
           }
        }

        if let channel = dictionary["CATEGORY_NAME"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
           print("Channel is \(channel)")
           if let eventName = channel["EVENT_NAME"] as? NSNumber {
              print ("Event name is \(eventName)")
           }
        }

     } else {

         if let array = jsonResult as? NSArray {
            for element in array {
               print(element)
            }
         }

         if let array = jsonResult as? [AnyObject] {
            for element in array {
               print(element)
            }
         }
     }
 }

 parse (["EVENT_ID":["EVENT_NAME" : events ]])
 return ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is just an example to get a return of your results. I suggest using a two-dimensional array. I hope I was of your help.

```
func parse (jsonResult: AnyObject?) ->(Dictionary<String,NSNumber>){

    var myDictionary = [String: NSNumber]()

    if let dictionary = jsonResult as? NSDictionary {

        if let event = dictionary["EVENT_ID"] as? NSDictionary {
            print("Event is \(event)")
            if let eventName = event["EVENT_NAME"] as? NSNumber {
                print ("Event name is \(eventName)")
                myDictionary["key1"] = eventName
            }
        }

        if let channel = dictionary["CATEGORY_NAME"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
            print("Channel is \(channel)")
            if let eventName = channel["EVENT_NAME"] as? NSNumber {
                print ("Event name is \(eventName)")
                myDictionary["key2"] = eventName
            }
        }

    } else {

        if let array = jsonResult as? NSArray {
            for element in array {
                print(element)
                //suppose an array are numbers
                myDictionary[String(element)] = element as? NSNumber
            }
        }

        if let array = jsonResult as? [AnyObject] {
            for element in array {
                print(element)
                //suppose an array are numbers
                myDictionary[String(element)] = element as? NSNumber
            }
        }
    }

    return myDictionary
}
```